# How to pass autocomplete dialog with <Enter> key while cword equals autocomplete value in vim?

Tags: vim, autocomplete

When I press `<Enter>` after typing `do` I can't pass to a new line. I can press `<Enter>` key 100 times and will see this autocomplete suggestion until I don't cancel it. The simplest way to omit this is to press `<Space>` and then `<Enter>` for a new line.

[image]

My `.vimrc` - https://github.com/vadimshvetsov/dotfiles/blob/master/vim/.vimrc

Comment: Have you tried disabling all plugins? If this solves the issue, then try reenabling one plugin at a time to figure out which one is causing trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like my configuration for `prabirshrestha/asyncomplete.vim` was wrong.

Finally end up with adding this entry and now `<Enter>` works:

```
inoremap <expr> <CR> pumvisible() ? asyncomplete#close_popup() . "\<CR>" : "\<CR>"
```